# How to assign unique_ptr<base> from a multiple inherited class object?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, unique-ptr

I have this code I am trying to assign unique_ptr of a base class from a multiple inherited class object. I got compiling error below:

> ````
> ‘std::unique_ptr<I>’ and ‘std::_MakeUniq<C>::__single_object {aka
> std::unique_ptr<C, std::default_delete<C> >}’)    a =
> make_unique<C>();
>      ^ ```
> ````

Is it possible to do it this way?

```
#include <memory>     

class I {
};

class A : public I {
};

class B : public I {
};

class C : virtual public A, virtual public B {
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unique_ptr<I> a;
    a = make_unique<C>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that inheritance tree is messed up. If you going to use multiple virtual inheritance from `I` in `C` then both `A` and `B` must inherit it virtually, otherwise `C` will end up with two `I` sub objects causing conversion problems:

```
class A : public  virtual I {
};

class B : public virtual I {
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It compiled successfully with your change.